# loop over the time till it reaches end time with specific interval

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to get all the time slots in a day with specified time interval (time interval is 2 hours i'e 120 minutes) like this

```
<?php

$start=strtotime('08:00');
$end=strtotime('18:00');

for ($i=$start + $k; $i<=$end - 1; $i = $i + 120*60) {
    echo date('g:i A',$i) . " - " . date('g:i A',$i  + 120*60 ) . '<br>';
}

?>
```

The above code outputs

```
8:00 AM - 10:00 AM
10:00 AM - 12:00 PM
12:00 PM - 2:00 PM
2:00 PM - 4:00 PM
4:00 PM - 6:00 PM
```

I'm trying to get the output something like below

```
8:00 AM - 10:00 AM
9:00 AM - 11:00 PM
10:00 AM - 12:00 PM
11:00 AM - 01:00 PM
12:00 PM - 02:00 PM
01:00 PM - 03:00 PM
02:00 PM - 04:00 PM
03:00 PM - 05:00 PM
04:00 PM - 06:00 PM
```

The time should not exceed 6 PM, I'm pretty new to PHP, can someone please help me on this, thanks

Comment: Use Carbon/DateTime and CarbonInterval/DateTimeInterval.

Comment: Thanks for the info but is there any way without using CarbonInterval/DateTimeInterval?

Comment: Yes, but why on earth wouldn't you?

Comment: @Amelia because this is a simple loop and does not need over-complicating.  Also, because the OP is 'pretty new to PHP' and is just looking for some help with their loop structure...

Comment: @MaggsWeb "that simple loop" is reduced to 1 line with a DateTimeInterval.

Comment: @Amelia solutions by obscurity do not help people learn..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `while` loop, as it makes for easier readble code.

```
$start = strtotime('08:00');
$end   = strtotime('18:00');

while ($start <= $end) {

    // Set dates to display
    $date1 = $start;        
    $date2 = $start + (120*60);

    echo date('g:i A',$date1) . " - " . date('g:i A',$date2) . '<br>';

    // Increment Start date
    $start += (60*60);

}


// 8:00 AM - 10:00 AM
// 9:00 AM - 11:00 AM
// 10:00 AM - 12:00 PM
// 11:00 AM - 1:00 PM
// 12:00 PM - 2:00 PM
// 1:00 PM - 3:00 PM
// 2:00 PM - 4:00 PM
// 3:00 PM - 5:00 PM
// 4:00 PM - 6:00 PM
// 5:00 PM - 7:00 PM
// 6:00 PM - 8:00 PM
```

Comment: Yes, Its more readable now, thanks but the above output is same, can you please help me to get the exact result as i want? Thanks alot