# loop over start-end time add minutes with next day

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to add 15 minutes to given times till the end time is reached. I have been looking at [loop over the time till it reaches end time with specific interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209383/loop-over-the-time-till-it-reaches-end-time-with-specific-interval) but this solution helps only for times within the same day.

In case as shown below it will not work.

```
$startTime = '16:00';
$endTime = '02:00';
```

The output I am looking for is as follow:

```
16:00
16:15
16:30
16:45
17:00
17:15
17...
.....
01:45
02:00
```

And let's say it is now 16:13 how can I then start the output from 16:30? or even better 30 mins later for example, at 16:45.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the next solution can help:

```
<?php
// get current time and round it to next half hour
$start = (intdiv(time(),(30 * 60)) + 1) * (30*60);

// since intdiv introduced in PHP 7 in previous PHP versoins
// intval() function can be used instead
$start = (intval(time()/(30 * 60)) + 1) * (30*60);

$end   = strtotime('02:00');

// if end time less then start add one day
if ($end < $start) $end += 60 * 60 * 24;

while ($start <= $end) {

    echo date('H:i',$start) . PHP_EOL;

    // Increment Start date
    $start += (15*60);

}
```

[share PHP code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=cd5a389d4af00b2fd8c8473283cb045b&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: many thanks for your answer. unfortunately intdiv will not work since I am using php 5.6.40. using without intdiv gives me entire different outputs.
$x = time();
$y = ((30 * 60) + 1) * (30*60);
$start = $x/$y; any alternative for legacy?

Comment: In PHP 5 use `$start = (intval(time()/(30 * 60)) + 1) * (30*60);` instead. https://phpize.online/?phpses=0f0318774d53228c4fe4baf40358a06f&sqlses=null&php_version=php5&sql_version=mysql57